# Google Analytics Outbound Click Dataroom (in my own server)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've recently finished working with Google API to transport all of the Google Analytics data into my own database.  However, I realized that I will have to run my script constantly to get the data up-to-date daily (Or run Cron to do it everyday).

Can someone suggest me a different solution? I've seen from somewhere that putting "some" code in the Javascript to pass the event variable to both Google Analytics and my own server, which I think is more complete solution. I've been searching through the web to find this solution, and I'm continuing to do so at the moment. I am very new to this and any help or direction will be very much appreciated. Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

With the (soon to be deprecated) asychronous Analytics code (ga.js) there are the `_setLocalGifPath` and `_setLocalRemoteServerMode` methods (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiUrchin#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setLocalRemoteServerMode)) that allowed to send raw data to a local server. This was for backward compatibilty with the (now defunct) Urchin Analytics software (Google acquired Urchin in the early 2000s and developed their product into what is now Google Analytics).

Since there is now completely new Analytics code based on the measurement protocol this does not work with Universal Analytics.

Edited to add: Refering to your comment, you can set a [hit callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) for interaction events (pageviews, events etc). This is a custom Javascript function that is triggered to moment Universal Analytics sends an interaction hit. However you cannot use this to get exactly the same data Analytics gets - with Universal Analytics the data is evaluated on the server, so you don't have data about campaign source, session duration, pagedepth etc on the client side anymore (used to be the case with the "old" analytics). So I'm not sure hitCallback will be much help to you.

Comment: Thanks Eike so it seems like I do not want to try develop something that is soon to be deprecated?

Comment: Do you know if google have a trigger that can be set up to track outbound clicks and fire them off to my server when it's triggered?